# Where are these Demo Errors in my console coming from?

Tags: angular, typeerror, console.log

I have a smallish project I am working on. Angular 11. Using VS 2019. .net Core back end.

During dev there are no erroneous console errors in the browsers.

As soon as I push it out to my test environment I can open up the browser console and see hundreds of [image]

645 of them to be exact. Now I see the reference to .length so I went back in, searched the entire project and in every instance of using .length I encapsulated with a check to make sure there was an object to actually use .length against before it tries to do whatever it wants with that .length.

Patched them all.  Double checked them all.

Push to test environ.  645 "demo error" in the console again.

Everything seems to be running fine in my code. Components all function as they should and everything seems fine.  But debugging anything is a chore when the console is beaten to death by these errors.

Google isn't pointing me anywhere else to find any help.

Comment: Are you using document.getElementById('element-id'); if so try put it in (<HTMLElement>document.getElementById('element-id'));  and then check if that element is already render in dom. Your error could be result of many things if so can you show us the component level where this error might be happening.

Comment: Need the portion of HTML code and bit of component ts code to understand your problem